# My computer runs fine on inverter power but can't turn on from off state. Will using an UPS between computer and inverter fix the issue?

Tags: power-supply, power, ups

A 900 watt sine wave inverter (with battery) is connected to mains. The PSU of my computer is 1000 watts. When there is power outage, my computer runs perfectly fine. But if it is already off, I can't turn it ON during power outage. I'm assuming that it is because even though my computer doesn't use 1000 watts all the time, it requires that for a small interval during startup.

I want to get an UPS rated at 1200 watts (2200 VA) and connect it between the computer and wall (inverter provides power to the wall socket during outage).

My question is will the 1000 watt computer be able to startup on the UPS during power outage without tripping the mains?

Comment: I suggest a 1500 Watt unit for the surge current a 1000 Watt PSU could generate

Comment: @John I can probably get the 1500 Watt ups but will it trip the inverter at mains? The inverter at mains only provides 900 watts at most and the power is divided among different appliances. Will the UPS be able to recharge itself from inverter power without tripping it?

Comment: It should do. That may be a question for the Manufacturer. My own UPS keeps charged and then powers the equipment via the battery run inverter. That is how most sine wave units work.

Comment: @John Makes sense since the UPS shouldn't really be discharged as inverter has enough power to sustain running the computer except during startup (few microseconds).

Comment: A single standard electrical circuit at 120v is 15a or 1850w, but typically we limit ourselves to 1500w continuous.  We don't know how many outlets are on the same circuit as your computer, or what is plugged into them.

Comment: To test it out may be consider removing a few components from your PC. e.g. Remove GPU, Disks etc and simulate power outage by manually tripping the Mains and see if with lower Load, the system turns On or not when on Inverter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though the UPS can *supply* more current than the mains, it does not draw that amount from the mains, and should not trip the circuit breaker *if the PC does not do so by itself*.

How can the UPS do this? It *slowly* charges a battery, drawing perhaps a few hundred watts, at most. The battery provides a large amount of current, for a short time -- don't expect more than 10 minutes of operation from battery.

You can use a larger UPS than the existing 900 watt unit. Just find the maximum *input* current to the UPS, and be sure that it will not exceed that of the house wiring. (Likely, only a huge UPS used in a data center would draw too much current, though.)

It *is* possible to place multiple UPS units in series, as you state, so that the one closest to the wall outlet uses up *its* battery's charge first, then the next UPS starts. That is not an efficient way to extend run-time, though. Simpler would be to use an *external* battery of higher capacity. This [Hackaday article by Dan Maloney](https://hackaday.com/2023/12/15/mods-turn-junk-ups-into-a-long-endurance-beast/) describes such hardware modifications. **Caveat:** do not try this if you are not familiar with safety precautions when dealing with *mains voltages*, with *high currents*, with *hydrogen outgassing* if using lead-acid batteries, and with *charging requirements and fire hazards of lithium batteries*!

Another way to extend run-time is to *split the load*, e.g., use one UPS for the PC itself, and another for all peripherals. There is the added advantage as load on a battery decreases, its effective capacity *increases*. A *hypothetical* battery that can deliver 100 amperes for 6 minutes (10 A-h), might deliver 10 A for 120 min  (20 A-h), effectively *doubling* capacity at the reduced discharge rate (Your mileage may vary ;-).